# Foreign keys --SQL--Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

```
--drop tables, remove constraints
DROP TABLE NB_Customer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE NB_Call CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE NB_Topic CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE NB_Order CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE NB_Product CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE NB_Sales_Associate CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----
--create table statements
CREATE TABLE NB_Customer(
Customer_ID  NUMBER,
Customer_Name VARCHAR2(50),
Customer_Address VARCHAR2(70),
Customer_CITY VARCHAR2(25),
Customer_State VARCHAR2(5),
Customer_ZIP NUMBER,
Customer_Phone VARCHAR2(20),
Customer_Fax VARCHAR2(20),
Customer_Email VARCHAR2(60),
Customer_Website VARCHAR2(60),
Customer_Contact VARCHAR2(150));

CREATE TABLE NB_Call(
Call_ID NUMBER,
Sales_Person_ID NUMBER,
Customer_ID NUMBER,
Topic_ID NUMBER,
Call_Date DATE,
Call_Comments VARCHAR2(150));


CREATE TABLE NB_Topic(
Topic_ID NUMBER,
Topic_Description VARCHAR2(30));

CREATE TABLE NB_Order(
Order_ID NUMBER,
Customer_ID NUMBER,
Sales_Person_ID NUMBER,
Order_Date DATE,
Product_ID NUMBER,
Order_Quantity NUMBER,
Product_Price NUMBER,
Order_Amount NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE NB_Product(
Product_ID NUMBER,
Product_Description VARCHAR2(30),
Product_Cost NUMBER,
Product_Price NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE NB_Sales_Associate(
Sales_Person_ID NUMBER,
Sales_Person_Name VARCHAR2(50),
Sales_Person_Last_Name VARCHAR2(50),
Sales_Person_Cellphone VARCHAR2(20),
Sales_Person_email VARCHAR2(50));

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------
--Primary key Alter statements
ALTER TABLE NB_Customer
ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Call
ADD CONSTRAINT Call_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(Call_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Topic
ADD CONSTRAINT Topic_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(Topic_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Order
ADD CONSTRAINT  Order_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Product
ADD CONSTRAINT  Product_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(Product_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Sales_Associate
ADD CONSTRAINT Sales_Person_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(Sales_Person_ID);

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----
--Foreign key statements

ALTER TABLE NB_Call
ADD CONSTRAINT Call_Customer_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Customer_ID) REFERENCES NB_Customer (Customer_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Call
ADD CONSTRAINT Call_Topic_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Topic_ID) REFERENCES NB_Topic (Topic_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Call
ADD CONSTRAINT Call_Sales_Associate_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Sales_Person_ID) REFERENCES NB_Sales_Associate (Sales_Person_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Order
ADD CONSTRAINT Order_Sales_Associate_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Sales_Person_ID) REFERENCES NB_Sales_Associate (Sales_Person_ID);


ALTER TABLE NB_Order
ADD CONSTRAINT Order_Customer_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Customer_ID) REFERENCES NB_Customer (Customer_ID);

ALTER TABLE NB_Order
ADD CONSTRAINT Order_Product_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Product_ID) REFERENCES NB_Product (Product_ID);
```

I had to errors -- 2 Errors:

> Ora-22291 integrity constraint (call_sales_Associate_FK) violated parent key not found.

I have sales_Person_ID  as a primary key on the table NB_Sales _Associate.

> Ora-22291 integrity constraint (order_product_FK) violated parent key not found.

I have product_ID as a primary key in the table NB_Product.

Comment: Do any of your tables contain data at this moment? I wouldn't expect these errors to be thrown by empty tables, and none of the code you have posted seems to populate tables with data, so it is unlikely to be throwing the error. More likely that you've posted your table create script but not the data fill script?

Comment: `please help me` ... you need to help us by telling us which of the hundred lines of code you posted has the problem.

Comment: Yes, I put data into the tables

Comment: Dllia, **none** of the code you have included so far in the question is relevant to the error. *The error comes after the code to create the tables.* We need to see the code that `puts data into the tables`.

Comment: ALTER TABLE NB_Order
ADD CONSTRAINT Order_Product_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Product_ID) REFERENCES NB_Product (Product_ID);

Comment: ALTER TABLE NB_Call
ADD CONSTRAINT Call_Sales_Associate_FK FOREIGN KEY
(Sales_Person_ID) REFERENCES NB_Sales_Associate (Sales_Person_ID);

Comment: This are the constraints .

Comment: oki, I try to paste here but , do not let me

Comment: I will posted all again thanks

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/407845-foreign-key-errors-oracle-sql/

Comment: I put all the code there , because here do not let me

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of errors are caused when you insert data into a child table and there is no matching data record in the parent table

When done in a transaction the insert can sometimes be done to the child table first, so long as: 1) the parent is populated during the same transaction and, 2) the constraint was created as "deferrable". Deferred constraints are validated upon transaction commit rather than upon issuing of every sql statement. None of your constraints are deferrable, by the way (but you could alter them so that they are)

Example, your `nb_call` table is keyed to the `nb_call_sales_associate` table. Attempting to insert a record into `nb_call` with a `sales_associate_id` value of 1, will only work if there is already a record in `nb_call_sales_associate` also with a `sales_associate_id` of 1

Either change the order in which you insert data so that parent records are inserted first, or create deferrable constraints and do it in a transaction. You can also disable the constraints, load the data and enable them again, but you'd only do this for initial bulk data setup, you wouldn't do it as part of a production system normal operation

If you aren't sure which tables are parents, read your foreign keys section: the table after the keyword REFERENCES is a parent table of the table mentioned first. Draw yourself a tree of the parent and children. When inserting data insert into the parent nodes of a particular child first:

[image]

I've numbered the tables as one example insert order. None of your parent tables are also children of other tables, which makes things a bit easier.

You can only insert to a table if the tables it is connected to above, already have data with matching id. I didnt write the column names, cos I could only find a rather blunt sharpie, and that would have cluttered the diagram up a lot!

Comment: Could you please elaborate your comment, "when done in a transaction the insert can be done to the child table first, so long as the parent is populated during the same transaction"? Perhaps share in what database product you believe this is possible?

Comment: I've added some info/reworded/clarified- thanks for the prompt! More info, see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:671629032835

Comment: thanks , I pupulated the tables first . them I put the constrains and work perfect . thank you again . =)